# Valid fields while Inserting a contact using google shared contact api using python

Tags: python, gdata-python-client

trying to add a contact
below is sample code from api
**where can i get all the valid fields like organization etc and some sample python code for that?**

```
new_contact = gdata.contacts.ContactEntry(title=atom.Title(text=name))
new_contact.content = atom.Content(text=notes)
# Create a work email address for the contact and use as primary.
new_contact.email.append(gdata.contacts.Email(address=primary_email,
    primary='true', rel=gdata.contacts.REL_WORK))
# Add extended properties to add data which is used in your application.
new_contact.extended_property.append(gdata.ExtendedProperty(
    name='favourite flower', value='daisy'))
sports_property = gdata.ExtendedProperty(name='sports')
sports_property.SetXmlBlob('<dance><salsa/><ballroom_dancing/></dance>')
new_contact.extended_property.append(sports_property)

# Send the contact data to the server.
contact_entry = gd_client.CreateContact(new_contact)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty full list of attributes in the [gdata-python-client source code](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/contacts/data.py) (see the [PersonEntry](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/contacts/data.py#347) and [ContactEntry](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/contacts/data.py#398) classes) and some [example code for using the client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/contacts/contacts_example.py) as well.

Comment: Found by Pradeep  [link]http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/hg/tests/gdata_tests/data_smoke_test.py